# How access asp session from aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp-classic

I am loading classic ASP page in the frame of ASPX page. when i reset IIS the classic ASP sessions are deleted, but asp.net sessions are not, because i am using State server session state for ASPX page.I want to delete all sessions of ASPX page when sessions from ASP page are deleted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe some code or configuration hints from your implementation would help to make your question easier to answer.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to build a mechanism for when the session has ended in classic asp to contact the aspx project to tell it to kill it's session.  It could be as simple as triggering a blank aspx page that has some code to kill the axpx session before doing some type of redirect.

Without further details it's hard to offer much more advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could create and ASPX page in your (.net) application that simple clears all the session for ASP.net application. Now when the session in the ASP application is cleared then simply call this ASPX page from your ASP application (you may just open it inside a frame if you do not want to redirect to that aspx page.).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to put something in the global.asa of your Classic ASP Application that resets the ASP.NET Application pool on startup.  Because you don't want to give your Classic ASP Environment privileges on the system, you should probably write a COM+ Service that you can call from ASP to do it.

```
<script language=VBScript runat=Server>
    Sub Application_OnStart
        Application.Lock

        'Restart ASP.NET Application Pool

        Application.UnLock
    End Sub
</script>
```